# Error when I try to install php 5.4

Tags: php, centos, installation, centos6

I get this error when I try to install php 5.4 on cents 6.4

`php - v`

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies


[root@centos145 ~]# rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
Retrieving http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.LytgA6: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID cf4c4ff9: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy from install of webtatic-release-6-5.noarch conflicts with file from package webtatic5-release-5.1-4.noarch
       file /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic-archive.repo from install of webtatic-release-6-5.noarch conflicts with file from package webtatic5-release-5.1-4.noarch
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic-testing.repo from install of webtatic-release-6-5.noarch conflicts with file from package webtatic5-release-5.1-4.noarch
[root@centos145 ~]# yum install php54w
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
 * extras: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * updates: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * webtatic-el5: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php54w.x86_64 0:5.4.39-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common = 5.4.39-1.w5 for package: php54w-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-cli = 5.4.39-1.w5 for package: php54w-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: php54w-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: php54w-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2 will be installed
---> Package php54w-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.39-1.w5 will be installed
---> Package php54w-common.x86_64 0:5.4.39-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: php54w-common-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Conflict: php54w-common-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
Error: Package: php54w-common-5.4.39-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic-el5)
       Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@centos145 ~]#
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe this one can help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90819/php-upgrade-error-php-5-3-3-to-php-5-4-19-on-centos-6-4

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS 6, PHP 5.3.3 is the latest version of PHP available through the official CentOS package repository. Keep in mind, even though PHP 5.3.3 was released July 22, 2010, the official CentOS 6 PHP package was updated November 24, 2013. Why? Critical bug fixes are backported. See this question for more information: "Why are outdated packages installed by yum on CentOS? (specifically PHP 5.1) How to fix?"

If you'd like to use a more recent version of PHP, Les RPM de Remi offers CentOS PHP packages via a repository that you can add to the yum package manager. To add it as a yum repository, [follow the site's instructions](http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/centos-5-or-centos-6-upgrade-php-to-php-54-or-php-55.htm).